# Better way of writing form inputs to global variables?

Tags: javascript, forms, global-variables

Here is my HTML for the form.

```
<body>
<form onsubmit="return handleSubmit(this)" id="form1">
  <h1>Choose your words!</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <label>First Noun: <input type="text" name="noun1" ></label><br>
    <label>Second Noun: <input type="text" name="noun2"></label><br>
    <label>First Adjective: <input type="text" name="adjective1"></label><br>
    <label>Second Adjective: <input type="text" name="adjective2"></label><br>
    <label>First Verb: <input type="text" name="verb1"></label><br>
    <label>Second Verb: <input type="text" name="verb2"></label><br>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" id="pushMe">Create Mad Lib</button>
</form>
<div id="placeholder">

</div>
```

Here is the function that runs when I press the button. The variables are global variables declared above this function, with no value. Example var noun1;

```
function handleSubmit(form) {
  noun1 = form.querySelector('input[name=noun1]').value;
  noun2 = form.querySelector('input[name=noun2]').value;
  adjective1 = form.querySelector('input[name=adjective1]').value;
  adjective2 = form.querySelector('input[name=adjective2]').value;
  verb1 = form.querySelector('input[name=verb1]').value;
  verb2 = form.querySelector('input[name=verb2]').value;

  return false;
}
```

Is there a better way of getting my form inputs written to my global variables to later write to the webpage?

Comment: Why are you using global variables at all?

Comment: I am using another function to write the value of the global variable to the DOM, so I thought I couldn't just leave my variables inside the function...

Comment: That's true, you cannot make them local to the `handleSubmit` function. But that doesn't mean that they should be global. Declare the variables in a scope that is accessible from both functions.

Comment: so wouldn't that just be one big function?

Comment: @maxwelldem It would, and at first that might seem strange. But it's a common JavaScript pattern to use functions to enclose scope.

Comment: So how would it look, with my return exiting the function, I can't add my other functions to the handleSubmit().  Do I add 'var' infront of the variables, and include my other functions inside handleSubmit() before the return?

Answer (score 0):

yes much better option are there you can use  namespaces by using this you can avoid no of global variables.

```
var formVal = formVal ||{};

function handleSubmit(form) {
  formVal.noun1 = form.querySelector('input[name=noun1]').value;
  formVal.noun2 = form.querySelector('input[name=noun2]').value;
  formVal.adjective1 = form.querySelector('input[name=adjective1]').value;
  formVal.adjective2 = form.querySelector('input[name=adjective2]').value;
  formVal.verb1 = form.querySelector('input[name=verb1]').value;
  formVal.verb2 = form.querySelector('input[name=verb2]').value;

  return false;
}
```

Or if you are dealing with global variable you should wrapp your code in a function  There is a slight performance advantage since it is faster to look things up in the local scope instead of having to walk up the scope chain into the global scope.

```
(function(window,undefined){
//your code
})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

All named form controls are available as properties of the form. Also, every form has an [*elements*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#dom-form-elements) collection that is all the controls in the form. So you can iterate over all the controls and process them however you wish, e.g.

```
// In global scope
var global = this;

function handleSubmit(form) {
  var control, controls = form.elements;
  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];
    if (global.hasOwnProperty(control.name)) {
      global.name = control.name.value;
    }
  }
}
```

However, that is pretty dangerous. If any of your form controls has a name that is the same as a standard property of the global/window object, it will overwrite it (e.g. *name*). It would be much better to store the values in an object, so you can do:

```
var global = {noun1:'', noun2:'', adjective1:'', adjective2:'', verb1:'', verb2:''};
```

but perhaps give the object a name other than *global*. Also, the *name* property isn't required to be unique, so you should deal with cases where controls have the same name (e.g. radio buttons).

But better again would be to give the controls you want to deal with a specific attribute value, say a class. Then you can test for the class and do whatever with the control's value.